# Store decimal places up to two decimal places in Oracle

Tags: oracle, floating-point

How to store `1.7` as `1.70` in `oracle 11g` database *`i.e`* with a trailing 0.

As in MySQL `floats(5,2)` serves the purpose.

In oracle I have used `number(5,2)` but this does not solve the purpose.

Please Help.

Comment: What the issue, how it store 1.70 ?

Comment: In MySQL a float(5,2) field stores 1.70 even if the value supplied is 1.7. Where as the case is not applicable in oracle and I need to have two decimal places for that particular field. If the value supplied is 1.72 or 1.75 then every thing is okay, but the process breaks when the value supplied has a single decimal digit.

Comment: the last zero does not have any meaning in number data type and this is why you cannot store it this way. You could visualize it if you want using to_char() function

Comment: Acknowledge, that the trailing 0 has no mathematical significance, but is there a way to explicitly store trailing 0. Maybe altering oracle system variables or any other way round because I cannot edit the column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL*PLUS, you need to set number format first to get the trailing zero after decimal.

```
SQL> select 1.1 as col1 from dual;

      COL1
----------
       1.1
SQL>  SET NUMFORMAT "999.99" -- set the format
SQL> select 1.1 as col1 from dual;

   COL1
-------
   1.10
SQL>
```

Else in pl/sql you need to use to_char function.

```
SQL> set numformat ""  --Reset back to normal
SQL> select to_char(1.1, '999.99') as col1 from dual;

COL1
----------------------------
   1.10
SQL>
```

If you want it for a particular column name in SQL*Plus then use columns command with format

```
SQL> column del_rate format 999.99
SQL> select 1.1 as del_rate from dual;

DEL_RATE
--------
    1.10
```

Comment: Hi San, before updating the number format, I have a query, will this NUMFORMAT update the number format system wide ? Is it possible to set the NUMFORMAT for that particular column only ?

Comment: If you want if for particular column (for current session), I have updated the answer, just check it. However, NUMFORMAT update the number format system wide for the current session only.